# OpenGL closing program that I try include animation

Tags: opengl, c#-3.0

I have a simple model of spacecraft building by glut libraries and I need that my model will rotate in the obtained angles (they will calculate). I'm watching a lot of tutorials but I can't release animation >: My program is just closed that I trying compile with using animation. Help me please

```
        namespace Runge_Kuta_1._6
```

{

```
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AnT1.InitializeContexts();
        Glut.glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);

    }
    void Timer(int value)
    {
        Display();
        Gl.glRotated(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Glut.glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    private void AnT1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // инициализация Glut 
        Glut.glutInit();
        Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_RGB | Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);

        // очитка окна 
        Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);

        // установка порта вывода в соотвествии с размерами элемента anT 
        Gl.glViewport(0, 0, AnT1.Width, AnT1.Height);


        // настройка проекции 
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Glu.gluPerspective(45, (float)AnT1.Width / (float)AnT1.Height, 0.1, 200);
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // настройка параметров OpenGL для визуализации 
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Draw();
    }
    void Draw()
    {
        //основание
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.7, 2, 60, 60);

        //каркас основания
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.7, 2, 20, 20);

        //соединение №1
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 1, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.02, 1, 40, 40);

        //соединение №1 каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 1, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.02, 1, 5, 5);

        //антенна
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 1, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(170, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.4, 0.05, 40, 40);

        //антенна каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 1, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(170, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.4, 0.05, 20, 20);

        //соединение №2
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-0.5, 0.025, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(178, 1, 0, 1);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.02, 0.8, 40, 40);

        //соединение №2 каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-0.5, 0.025, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(178, 1, 0, 1);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.02, 0.8, 2, 2);

        //антенна №2
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(0.35, 0.025, -6.5);
        Gl.glRotated(178, 1, 0, 1);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.4, 0.05, 20, 20);

        //антенна №2 каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(0.35, 0.025, -6.5);
        Gl.glRotated(178, 1, 0, 1);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.4, 0.05, 10, 10);

        //соединение №3
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0.2, -4.5);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.02, 0.2, 40, 40);

        //соединение №3 каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0.2, -4.5);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.02, 0.2, 5, 5);

        //антенна №3
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0.3, -4.48);
        Gl.glRotated(180, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.25, 0.05, 20, 20);

        //антенна №3 каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0.3, -4.48);
        Gl.glRotated(180, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.25, 0.05, 20, 20);

        //соединение №4
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-0.45, 0.4, -5.5);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.02, 0.4, 40, 40);

        //соединение №4 каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-0.45, 0.4, -5.5);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.02, 0.4, 10, 10);

        //антенна №4
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-0.45, 0.55, -5.48);
        Gl.glRotated(180, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.45, 0.05, 20, 20);

        //антенна №4 каркас
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(-0.45, 0.55, -5.48);
        Gl.glRotated(180, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.45, 0.05, 20, 20);

        Gl.glPopMatrix();
        Gl.glFlush();
        AnT1.Invalidate();
    }
    void Display()
    {
        Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
        x[0] = x0; y[0] = y0; z[0] = z0;
        Gamma[0] = Gamma0; Psi[0] = Psi0; Phi[0] = Phi0;
        while (t0 <= T)
        {
            Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Label:
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                fx = -y[i] - z[i];
                fy = x[i] + 0.2 * y[i];
                fz = 0.2 + (x[i] - 5.7) * z[i];
                Kx[i] = h * fx;
                Ky[i] = h * fy;
                Kz[i] = h * fz;
                x[1] = x[0] + 0.5 * Kx[0];
                x[2] = x[0] + 0.5 * Kx[1];
                x[3] = x[0] + Kx[2];
                y[1] = y[0] + 0.5 * Ky[0];
                y[2] = y[0] + 0.5 * Ky[1];
                y[3] = y[0] + Ky[2];
                z[1] = z[0] + 0.5 * Kz[0];
                z[2] = z[0] + 0.5 * Kz[1];
                z[3] = z[0] + Kz[2];
            }
            Ex = Math.Abs(2 * (Kx[0] - Kx[1] - Kx[2] + Kx[3]) * divBy3);
            Ey = Math.Abs(2 * (Ky[0] - Ky[1] - Ky[2] + Ky[3]) * divBy3);
            Ez = Math.Abs(2 * (Kz[0] - Kz[1] - Kz[2] + Kz[3]) * divBy3);
            Eps1 = Eps * divBy8;
            if (Ex > Eps | Ey > Eps | Ez > Eps)
            {
                h /= 2;
                goto Label;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                fGamma = x[0] * System.Math.Sin(Phi[0]) + y[0] * System.Math.Cos(Phi[0]);
                fPsi = 1 / (System.Math.Cos(Gamma[0])) * (x[0] * System.Math.Cos(Phi[0]) - y[0] * System.Math.Sin(Phi[0]));
                fPhi = z[0] - (System.Math.Sin(Gamma[0]) / (System.Math.Cos(Gamma[0]))) * (x[0] * System.Math.Cos(Phi[0]) - y[0] * System.Math.Sin(Phi[0]));
                KGamma[i] = h * fGamma;
                KPsi[i] = h * fPsi;
                KPhi[i] = h * fPhi;
                Gamma[1] = Gamma[0] + 0.5 * KGamma[0];
                Gamma[2] = Gamma[0] + 0.5 * KGamma[1];
                Gamma[3] = Gamma[0] + KGamma[2];
                Psi[1] = Psi[0] + 0.5 * KPsi[0];
                Psi[2] = Psi[0] + 0.5 * KPsi[1];
                Psi[3] = Psi[0] + KPsi[2];
                Phi[1] = Phi[0] + 0.5 * KPhi[0];
                Phi[2] = Phi[0] + 0.5 * KPhi[1];
                Phi[3] = Phi[0] + KPhi[2];
            }
            xx = x[0] + (Kx[0] + 2 * Kx[1] + 2 * Kx[2] + Kx[3]) * divBy6;
            yy = y[0] + (Ky[0] + 2 * Ky[1] + 2 * Ky[2] + Ky[3]) * divBy6;
            zz = z[0] + (Kz[0] + 2 * Kz[1] + 2 * Kz[2] + Kz[3]) * divBy6;
            GGamma = Gamma[0] + (KGamma[0] + 2 * KGamma[1] + 2 * KGamma[2] + KGamma[3]) * divBy6;
            PPsi = Psi[0] + (KPsi[0] + 2 * KPsi[1] + 2 * KPsi[2] + KPsi[3]) * divBy6;
            PPhi = Phi[0] + (KPhi[0] + 2 * KPhi[1] + 2 * KPhi[2] + KPhi[3]) * divBy6;
            Gl.glRotated(Gamma[0], 1, 0, 0);
            Gl.glRotated(Psi[0], 0, 1, 0);
            Gl.glRotated(Phi[0], 0, 0, 1);
            Gl.glPopMatrix();
            x[0] = xx;
            y[0] = yy;
            z[0] = zz;
            Gamma[0] = GGamma;
            Psi[0] = PPsi;
            Phi[0] = PPhi;
            t0 += h;
            Glut.glutMainLoop();

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell how these code fragments are connected. Do you have a `glutMainLoop()` somewhere?

Comment: no i don't. include in my code and all the same doesn't work. update my code: display will calculate angles that need to rotate my spacecraft

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems from a quick scan through the code:

- Your `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` calls are unbalanced. As the name of these functions suggest, they manage a matrix stack. You need to pop as many stack entries as you push in your `Draw()` method, otherwise your stack will gradually increase in size, and overflow.
- You added a `glutMainLoop()` call after my suggestion in the comment, but that doesn't look like it's in the right place. I'm not really familiar with the C# program structure, but it's typically called after you finished your initialization, and registered all your GLUT functions. Based on everything else in there, that might be at the end of `AnT1_Load()`. But you may want to look for some C# OpenGL examples to see where they normally place these calls.

Comment: hm, in the first a problem: just my model doesn't drawing if using one push and pop and i used a many push and pop >: maybe can will optimise that pard of code? Well calling glutMainLoop() will closed my form with animation D: will include MainLoop at the end of AnT1_Load()